# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Trying to insert a lot of records from a MySQL database into SQL Server(2005 SQLExpress) database. Here's the query and the error from PHP. I am not understanding it. All opening strings are closed properly but still..

```
INSERT INTO tbl_email (uniq_id, Respondent_ID, Bcode, BID, Email, Voornaam, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Geslacht, Adres, Huisnummer, Toevoeging, Postcodecijfers, Postcodeletters, Woonplaats, Land, Telefoon1, Mobiel, Telefoon2, Matchkey, Profile, Geboortejaar, Geboortedatum, Leefsituatie, Gezinsgrootte, Inkomen, Beroep, Opleiding, Huis, Huisjaar, Huistype, Tuin, Auto, Beleggen, Kopenopafstand, Financien, Respondenttype, Charitype, Chari, Postcode, Huisdier, EV2, EV3, EV4, EV5, EV6, EV7, EV8, EV9, Aanmaakdatum, fk_ID_projectreactie, status_subscribed, unsubscribeddate, insertdatetime, editdatetime, to_delete) VALUES (6, "41", "288", "53", "test@hotmail.com", "a", "M", "", "0", "2", "0", "176", "", "5652", "EP", "a", "", "", "0", "0", "0", "", "0", "", "2", "2", "", "4", "4", "1", "2006", "", "", "", "1", "1", "", "3", "", "", "a", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "a", 0, 0, Null, Null, Null, 1)
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. (severity 15) in crn_export_mssql.php on line 94
```

What could be the problem. I ran this query singly through SQL Server management console and it accepted and inserted. I even ran this query in another PHP file and data was inserted. However, when I do it in a PHP loop then this problem., The code snippet is,

```
while(//get rows from mysql)
{ //create query on runtime
$query = $strInsertDump . '('.implode(', ', $arrInsertField).')';
$result = mssql_query($query, $mslink);
}
```

*Edit:*

I used PDO now and here's what the errorInfo returns.

```
Array
(
[0] => HY000
[1] => 20018
[2] => Incorrect syntax near ''. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]
[3] => -1
[4] => 5
[5] => OpenClient
)
```

Comment: you need to specify single quotes instead of double quotes. did u try that ?

Comment: could you provide a print of your `$query`?

Comment: That's... quite a few fields. Please reduce to a [representative sample statement](http://sscce.org), one that produces the same message but doesn't have any extraneous fields.

Comment: Miss Wijzenbeek from Eindhoven might not like her telephone number being posted like that?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_email (uniq_id, Respondent_ID, Bcode, BID, Email, Voornaam, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Geslacht) VALUES (6, "41", "288", "53", "test@hotmail.com", "Mijntje", "M", "", "Wijzenbeek", "2");
    Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. (severity 15) in crn_export_mssql.php on line 96`

The above query is simple but produces the same error.

Comment: I tried double-quotes instead of single-quotes. Simplified the query now but still the same.

Comment: My god. Format your post please.

Comment: Will give *Miss Wijzenbeek from Eindhoven* a call.

Comment: @Khuram: updates and clarifications for the question should be edited into the question, not posted as a comment.

Comment: @Khuram: the syntax error is a different issue and thus should be asked in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The old mssql extension is outdated. Switch to the [SQL Server PHP driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782) (the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) version), so you can use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), which are safer, more performant and won't suffer from any value coding issues, since values are kept separate from the rest of the statement.

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_email (uniq_id, Respondent_ID, Bcode, ...) 
                       VALUES (:uid, :rid, :bcode, ...)');
while (/* ... */) {
    $query->execute(array(':uid' => ..., ':rid' => ..., ':bcode' => ..., ...));
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems interesting, let me try that... Thanks

Comment: I used PDO but now it says record inserted but no error in PHP and also no records inserted. I have put the whole block inside Try/Catch and even the error_reporting is set to `E_ALL` but still nothing...

Comment: @Khuram: PDO will only throw exceptions if you set the [error mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Otherwise, you have to test the return value of [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.execute) and get the error info using [`PDOStatement::errorInfo`](http://php.net/PDO.errorInfo). Additionally, PDO will only issue a warning message if the error mode is `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`.

Comment: Hi Guys, I used PDO and here is what I received in errorInfo();

Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 20018
    [2] => Incorrect syntax near ''. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]
    [3] => -1
    [4] => 5
    [5] => OpenClient
)

Answer (score 0):

try stripping out all but essential NOT NULL column names and associated values, and then add them back in slowly.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_email (uniq_id, Respondent_ID)
) VALUES (6, "41")
```

Question: is "function.mssql-query" a PHP function?

It would be nice to see what SQL Server is receiving.  Perhaps enable some client side logging.  Your SQL looks visually okay to me.

Probably if you include the create table statement, that'll allow people to help a bit more.

Comment: mssql_query is a php function and yes it is connecting and SELECT statements are running fine, we just need to insert data into MSSQL one time. The data is inserting fine if I copy the query over but not through PHP. I am not sure anymore.

Comment: This is the most simple form of the query.

`INSERT INTO tbl_email (uniq_id, Respondent_ID, Bcode, BID, Email, Voornaam, Voorletters, Tussenvoegsel) VALUES (6, '41', '288', '53', 'test@hotmail.com', 'test', 'M', '');
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. (severity 15) in crn_export_mssql.php on line 96`

The first single-quote it recieves give error. however, if I run this query in SQL Server management tool then it inserts the record. The field itself is a nvarchar(250) and allows Null.

Comment: You can use profiler to see what SQL Server is receiving. SQL Server Express doesn't have profiler shipped in the package. Perhaps this free version will be helpful, but I must say I never used it.
http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/

At a side, you should consider using parameters in the query, this would sort out your issue for sure.